# How to remove newline from Phoenix log

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Phoenix have a usefull request log, but I need to remove the newlines it generates:

```
Processing with Example.show_account/2
  Parameters: %{}
  Pipelines: [:secure_api]
```

These newlines are defined on **Phoenix.Logger.phoenix_controller_call/4**

I tried a simple custom log format function with a **String.replace/4**, but it doesn't work because the function receives a **IOList** (fist time I've seen it), not a String.

What are my options to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The code in your answer will not work if the iolist is more nested than one level, e.g. `[["foo\nbar"]]`. I'd instead recommend converting the iolist to a `String` and then using `String.replace/3`:

```
iolist = [102, 111, 10, 111, [[["bar\n", 'baz']]]]

iolist |> IO.iodata_to_binary |> IO.inspect
iolist |> IO.iodata_to_binary |> String.replace("\n", "") |> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
"fo\nobar\nbaz"
"foobarbaz"
```

Comment: You're right, not only IOList could have nested lists, but even improper lists.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully tested, but this might work:

```
def remove_newline(msg) when is_list(msg), do: Enum.reject(msg, fn i -> i == 10 end)

def remove_newline(msg) when is_bitstring(msg), do: String.replace(msg, "\n", "")

def remove_newline(msg), do: msg
```

Comment: Please do not do this. `Enum.reject/2` and `String.replace/3` are both [could be] time-consuming and the last thing you probably want is to have a performance bottleneck in your logging code. `IOList` is fine enough to do what you want: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/elixir-and-io-lists-part-1-building-output-efficiently/